# Using a Spinner value in a calculation

Tags: java, android

Wondering if i can get some help with a problem i'm having? I have searched for the answer on here, and although i found a few relevant topics i'm still really struggling...

Below you can see that i'm using a Spinner asking the user to select either Large, Med or Small.

The selection is then issued to a TextView.

What i now want to do is assign a value to the 3 selections, Large = 6, Med = 4, Small =2.
Next there will be a EditText box for the user to add their own value.
Then i want to put the two values into a calculation (say * them in this example) putting the answer into a TextView.

Any help here would be great.

Many Thanks
Will

```
String[] items = { "Large", "Med", "Small" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.plugfan);
    Factor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Factor);

    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
            items);

    aa.setDropDownViewResource(
       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(aa);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    Factor.setText(items[position]);
}


public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    Factor.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to solve this (not the smartest one) is to have a paralell array:

```
int[] itemValues = { 6, 4, 2 };
```

In the method onItmeSelected you can setText using the itemValue, instead of items.

If you want a more OO-solution a new class that returns a list of Strings to use as a model for your spinner might be a beter solution (an enumeration might solve it too).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately i cant get it to work... not sure if im missing something or there are more requirements to get this going... have you tested the above theory and know it works?